# как убрать предупреждения при выполнении r-скрипта в командной строке?

Tags: cmd, r, warning

Запускаю [r](/questions/tagged/r) скрипт через `cmd`. Хочу в ответе получить только результат выполнения скрипта, а именно строку "Расчет выполнен!"

Но в процессе выполнения скрипта выходят предупреждения. От части из них мне удалось избавиться. Но одно остаётся. Причем, если запускать его через `RStudio`, то предупреждений нет, так как я добавила в параметры `warn=-1`

> you receive the following warning:
>   Attaching package: ‘zoo’
>   The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>   as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Как убрать это предупреждение.

Comment: вопрос снят. библиотеки включила в suppressMessage

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно помочь:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(zoo))
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/177111)

Comment: Как раз именно является ответом. Автор спрашивает "как убрать", я в ответ привожу строку кода.

Comment: тогда лучше такой вариант

Comment: Спасибо! suppressPackageStartupMessages помогло!

Comment: Тогда поставьте ответ как принятый :)

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативой предложенному варианту может быть такой:

```
library(zoo, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
```